# Does ExtJS7 multi application project (with workspace) support open tooling (Ext-gen, webpack)?

Tags: npm, webpack, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

Can I create multi application workspace project with ExtJS 7 and bring open-tooling (npm,webpack) to it?
I couldn't find any documentation for this.

Comment: They already have open tooling: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/guides/using_systems/using_npm/npm_migrate.html . You can convert applications one by one, it should work imo as you already build apps in workspace separately

Answer (score 0):

No, currently Sencha does not support that, but i think, they confirmed to be working on it.
Maybe with ExtJS 8 ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do you know if there is an official statement/confirmation from Sencha regrading this?